# How to use a webService in this function. $resource, with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

I have the following controller that serves me to fill a table with DataTable.
But there I use a json array, I want to consume a webservice that returns a json object. `http://localhost:8080/system/public/ws/users`. It returns an array of nose objects as I use it in that function to fill the table.

```
> .controller('dt_default',
    function($compile, $scope, $timeout, $resource, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.dt_data = [];
        vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
            .newOptions()
            .withDisplayLength(10)
            .withOption('initComplete', function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $compile($('.dt-uikit .md-input'))($scope);
                })
            });
        vm.dtColumnDefs = [
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(3),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(4),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(5)
        ];
        $resource('data/dt_data.json') 
           /* Here I get the json.
            * How can I use the webservice that returns an array of objects. 
            * Json with has only arrays
            */
            .query()
            .$promise
            .then(function(dt_data) {
                vm.dt_data = dt_data;
                console.log(dt_data);
            });
```

And the html I have it this way, as I would have to.

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in showCase.dt_data">
                        <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                        <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
                        <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
                        <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
                        <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
                        <td> 
                         <a href="#" data-uk-modal="{target:'#modal_header_footer'}"><i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-light-blue-900 uk-text-contrast"></i></a>
                         <a href="#" data-uk-modal="{target:'#modal_header_footer_eliminar'}"><i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-red-900 uk-text-contrast">&#xE872;</i></a>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Movemos la pregunta a SO en español, la intentamos traducir o la cerramos? Acá toca en inglés! :) // Should we move the question to SO en español, should we translate it or just close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

Take a look at this page: [Documentation](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#/serverSideProcessing)

```js
.controller('dt_default',
    function($compile, $scope, $timeout, $resource, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.dt_data = [];
        vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
            .newOptions()
            .withDisplayLength(10)
            .withOption('initComplete', function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $compile($('.dt-uikit .md-input'))($scope);
                })
            })
            .withOption('ajax', {
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/system/public/ws/users',
                type: 'GET',
            })
            .withOption('processing', true)
            .withOption('serverSide', true);
           
        vm.dtColumns = [
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Option').renderWith(data, type, full) {
            var el = '<a href="#" data-uk-modal="{target:\'#modal_header_footer\'}"><i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-light-blue-900 uk-text-contrast"></i></a>';
            })
      ];
```

```html
<div ng-controller="dt_default as dt_default">
    <table datatable="" dt-options="dt_default.dtOptions" dt-columns="dt_default.dtColumns" class="row-border hover"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: And what would be the variable that would use in ng-repeat

Comment: you dont need to use ng-repeat

Comment: :O, Interesting, but forgive me as I would stay in the html?

Comment: did you check the link? you must use DTColumnBuilder

Comment: Thank you very much, if I work, I only have to fix the page and perform a search in the table. I have a modal where I will edit the user information in this ng-model use how can I pass the parameter to the modal?